# Connect and publish with Tableau and Azure Analysis Services

Tags: data, visualization, data-science-model, tableau

My organization is migrating to another platform and we need to replicate the reports we have made with Power BI in Tableau, but the problem is that our server data is in Azure Analysis Services, but Tableau does not have support for this server, the closest is Microsoft SQL Analysis Services and we can connect there but not publish because Tableau does not allow to extract from a cube model, so my answer is has anyone been through this and how do you solve it? (this is in the middle time we migrate to another server)